# Перегрузка шаблона по наличию шаблонности у его параметра

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++

Упрощённо: имеются структуры (обертки над typetrait'ами) вида

```
template <class T, class F>
struct first {
    static const size_t value = F::template value<T>();
};

template <class T, template <class> class F>
struct second {
    static const size_t value = F<T>::value;
};
```

Вспомогательные структуры

```
struct foo {
    template <class T>
    static constexpr size_t value() { 
        return sizeof(T);
    }
};

template <class T>
struct bar {
    static const size_t value = sizeof(T);
};
```

И наконец использование:

```
static_assert(first<char, foo>::value == 1, "");
static_assert(second<char, bar>::value == 1, "");
```

---

Вопрос: как реализовать **first** и **second** так, чтобы они имели одно имя? Хочется вот такого шаблонного полиморфизма. Если это невозможно, то почему?

gcc 4.9.2, поэтому шаблонных переменных нет, к сожалению.

Comment: возможно вам нужно смотреть в сторону [enable_if](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, одинаковые имена у шаблонов классов могут быть только в случае, если это специализации (у шаблонов функций могут быть еще перегрузки, но у классов нет подобного механизма).
Чтобы специализировать шаблон, надо "уточнить" его параметры. Какие параметры могут быть у шаблона класса? Это:

- типы (`class T` или `typename T`)
- значения (`int N` или `size_t N`)
- другие шаблоны (`template <class T> class F`)
- ну и микс из вышеперечисленных

Проблема в том, что если шаблон задан с параметром-типом, то его нельзя специализировать параметром-значением или параметром-шаблоном.
Так что, похоже, что это:

> Если это невозможно, то почему?

в общем случае невозможно.
Ну а что можно сделать в вашем случае? Можно написать такую специализацию:

```
template <class T, class F>
struct first {
    static const size_t value = F::template value<T>();
};

template <class T, template <class> class F>
struct first<T, F<T>> {
    static const size_t value = F<T>::value;
};
```

и потом использовать ее в такой манере:

```
static_assert(first<char, foo>::value == 1, "");
static_assert(first<char, bar<char>>::value == 1, "");
static_assert(first<int, bar<int>>::value == 4, "");
static_assert(first<std::vector<int>, bar<std::vector<int>>>::value == 24, "");
```